# 301 redirect "/?" and "/?i=xxx" to "/"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

## Hi guys I have a problem with redirects. I try do a 301 of

```
www.example.com/? to www.example.com/
```

and also

```
www.example.com/?i=xxxx to www.example.com/
```

With this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^i=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

or with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^i=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ / R=301,L]
```

but it continues to add the `i=xxx` when I redirect to the new website...

## I want to redirect

- `/?` to `/`
- `/?i=xx` to `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
> ```

You need to add a `?` onto the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (effectively an empty query string). Otherwise, if you don't specify a query string then Apache automatically copies the query string from the request. The single `?` won't appear on the target - the query string is removed completely. For example:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^i=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here since you are not using *relative* substitutions.

Note: If you use WordPress, you should change `(.*)` to `[0-9]+` as otherwise it could break some internal functions like the preview of a post. Reference: https://xeedbeam.me/prevenir-contenido-duplicado-en-wordpress-con-htaccess-para-seo-parte-1/

Or - Alternatively, on Apache 2.4+ you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead.

```
 RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing.

**UPDATE:**

> I want to redirect `/?` to `/`

This is a bit more tricky as you can't determine (using just the `QUERY_STRING` variable) whether the query string is totally absent (ie. no `?`) or just empty (with `?` but nothing after it). However, you can check `THE_REQUEST` server variable that contains the actual request header (eg. "`GET /? HTTP/1.1`"). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/\?\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

However, this would unlikely be a problem for search engines. `example.com/` and `example.com/?` *should* be treated the same.